# Nested foreach with clusters

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow

I'd like to parallelize my code. The R initializes the clusters, but it doesn't distribute the work to the processor. In other words, I can create the workers, but it doesn't use the CPU capacity. My problem is given by

## I edit to complete form

I need to function to generate the data.

```
psim <- function(objects, vertices){
  if(vertices <= 2){
    stop("Insert a vertex number more than 2")
  }
  if(objects < 1){
    stop("Insert a valid objects number")
  }
  polygons <- NULL
  for(i in 1:objects) polygons[[i]] <- matrix(runif(vertices*2), ncol = 2)
  return(polygons)
}
```

## Function that is occurs the problems

More specifically in `foreach`.

```
#parallel is used to decide to use parallelization or not.
pfreq <- function(polygons, parallel = F){
## Very fast ## 
  np <- length(polygons)
  nv <- nrow(polygons[[1]])

  polygons1 <- matrix(0,nrow = nv, ncol = np)
  polygons2 <- matrix(0,nrow = nv, ncol = np)
  for(temp in 1:np){
    polygons1[ ,temp] <- polygons[[temp]][,1]
    polygons2[ ,temp] <- polygons[[temp]][,2]
  }
  minX <- min(polygons1)
  maxX <- max(polygons1)
  minY <- min(polygons2)
  maxY <- max(polygons2)

  ratioX <- (maxX - minX)/np
  ratioY <- (maxY - minY)/np

  rectangles <- list()
  l <- 1
  for(j in 1:(np)){
    for(i in 1:(np)){
      rectangles[[l]] <- matrix(c(minX + (i-1)*ratioX, minY + (j-1)*ratioY, minX + (i-1)*ratioX, minY + j*ratioY,
                        minX + i*ratioX, minY + j*ratioY, minX + i*ratioX, minY + (j-1)*ratioY), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
      l <- l + 1
    }
  }
  polygons <- lapply(polygons, function(x) as(x, "gpc.poly"))
  rectangles <- lapply(rectangles, function(x) as(x, "gpc.poly"))
  polygons_area <- sapply(polygons, function(x) rgeos::area.poly(x))

  n_rectangles <- length(rectangles)
## Very slow ##
  if(parallel){
    cores <- getDoParWorkers()
    cl <- makeCluster(cores, type = "SOCK")
    registerDoSNOW(cl)

    frequency <- foreach(k = 1 : np, .combine = "cbind",
                         .packages = c("rgeos", "base")) %:%
      foreach(l = 1 : n_rectangles, .combine = 'c') %dopar% 
      (
        area.poly(intersect(polygons[[k]], rectangles[[l]]))/polygons_area[k]
      )
    stopCluster(cl)
  }
############################################################
  frequency <- matrix(0, ncol = n_rectangles, nrow = np)
  for(k in 1:np){
    for(l in 1:n_rectangles){
      frequency[i, j] <- area.poly(intersect(polygons[[k]], rectangles[[l]]))/polygons_area[k]
    }
  }

  frequency <- matrix(frequency, ncol = length(polygons), byrow = F) 
  frequency <- matrix(apply(frequency, 1, sum), ncol = length(polygons))
  relative_frequency_temp <- frequency/length(polygons)

  return(relative_frequency_temp)
}

test <- psim(50, 3)
pfreq(test, T)
```

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: How long does one call to my.fun take?

Comment: I can't run one call. But when `n1 = 5` and `n2 = 25` the times is 1.91s with parallel and without parallel is 0.53s.

Comment: Of course you can run one call. Obviously you'd do that outside of foreach, preferably using the microbenchmark package. It looks like overhead is killing parallel performance. Without more information about the function no further help is possible.

Comment: Errata: One call with parallel the time is 0.7660439 secs and without parallel is 0.007999897 secs. I can!

Comment: There you have it. One call must be slow to justify overhead. Try parallelizing only the outer loop.

Comment: @RolandI put the complete function.